# Chrome placing divs in the wrong order

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, web

I'm working on a very simple website that is pretty much just HTML and CSS. The mock up I've made works well in Firefox but when I put it into chrome it does something weird. The the text I've put in a div tag is displaying under the end.

Here's the code, if you take it into chrome you should be able to see what I'm talking about. 
[HTML of Site](http://dpaste.com/hold/1609162/)
[CSS of Site](http://dpaste.com/hold/1609167/)

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zxt8d/  jsFiddle

Comment: Add relevant code to the question itself as well, please.

Comment: If you remove the image `<img src="./graphics/fishtank.jpg/"width="1090" />` the text shows up. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

It displays correctly if you set a height on the fishtank image.

```
<img src="./graphics/fishtank.jpg" width="1090" height ="10" />
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24B2w/1/)

Is the fishtank image a background image?  If so, you can put it as a background image in the parent div's CSS.